# Selecting Map over List in certain conditions

Tags: java

I have the below method in which I am creating multiple lists and counters.
I don't think this is the right approach from the Java point of view. I was
thinking I could use a map having key-value pair, and there should be the key
and its value type is a list. Could you please advise how my below code can
be changed to use maps instead and how it could be edited to make it more
meaningful.

```
public Map<String, Object> abclistcount(String Id)
{
    List<abcIdentifierabcobject> successfulboaabcIdentifierabcobjects = new ArrayList <abcIdentifierabcobject>();
    List<abcIdentifierabcobject> failureboaabcIdentifierabcobjects = new ArrayList <abcIdentifierabcobject>();
    List<abcIdentifierabcobject> exceptionboasettlement = new ArrayList <abcIdentifierabcobject>();
    List<abcIdentifierabcobject> successfulboasettlement = new ArrayList <abcIdentifierabcobject>();

    HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<defInfo> reportData = new ArrayList<defInfo>();

    List<abcIdentifierabcobject> abcIdentifierabcobjects = futuresFeedHome.getabcIdentifierabcobjects(fileIdentifier);

    //counter to track
    int failurecounterboafeed = 0;
    int failurecounterboasettlement =0;
    int sucessboasettlement =0;
    int successboacount=0;

    if (abcIdentifierabcobjects !=null  && abcIdentifierabcobjects.size()>0)
    {
        for (abcIdentifierabcobject f : abcIdentifierabcobjects)
        {
            defInfo abjkfeed = new defInfo();
            // INVALID_STATIC_DATA fails at boa_futures feed side itself
            if ("INVALID_STATIC_DATA".equalsIgnoreCase(f.getStatus())  /* INVALID RECORD*/)
            {
                failureboaabcIdentifierabcobjects.add(f) ;
                failurecounterboafeed++;
                abjkfeed.setHeader("Futures Intraday Report");
                abjkfeed.setData(failureboaabcIdentifierabcobjects);
                reportData.add(abjkfeed);
            }
            //if not fail in boa_futures_feed then

            successfulboaabcIdentifierabcobjects.add(f);
            successboacount++;
        }

        for (abcIdentifierabcobject f : successfulboaabcIdentifierabcobjects)
        {
            Settlement settlement = f.getSettlement();
            //tracking the records that are fail on boa_settlement side
            //futher filtering fail at GEN EX queue or Awaiting ack

            if (fwqConstants.AF_T_ZY_SETTLEMENT_EXCEPTION.equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()) || fwqConstants.AF_T_ZY_SETTLEMENT_SENT_EX.equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()))
            {
                exceptionboasettlement.add(f);
                failurecounterboasettlement++;
            }

            defInfo successfulpayments = new defInfo();
            //seprating the successful list of boa_settlement one in a seprate list
            if (fwqConstants.AF_T_ZY_COMPLETED.equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()) || fwqConstants.AF_T_ZY_SETTLEMENT_CREATED.equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()))
            {
                successfulboasettlement.add(f);
                sucessboasettlement++;
                successfulpayments.setHeader("Successful Payments");
                successfulpayments.setData(successfulboasettlement);
                reportData.add(successfulpayments);
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

I will correct the naming conventions but this time focus is on how to remove the many arraylists that I am using internally.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand your first paragraph, consider an edit

Comment: You need to shorten your variable names.  I'm all for using descriptive names, but `sucessfulboaabcIdentifierabcobjects` is incomprehensible, as are all the other lists.  Using random sequences of letters is NOT acceptable for primary source code in Java.  Functions and variables should be in `camelCase`, too, change that as well.

Comment: have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: I don't understand the question - is it about replacing the IdentifierObject lists with maps? Also, the counters dont seem to be used - what do you need them for?

Comment: @kutschkem question is about not to have so many array list as I am having rite now , want to use map instead

Comment: @user2355514 So is each list a "status" that the abcIdentifierAbcObject can have? Also; what does "abc" stand for? It seems to be everywhere. And is Boa a snake?

Comment: @user2355514 "i will correct the naming conventions but this time focus is on how to remove so many arraylist internally i am using". No one is saying you have to fix the naming conventions as a *requirement* for us to answer the question. **But** at present no one understands exactly what the code is supposed to do because most of the variable names are meaningless. One way or annother we need to understand what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

A list still makes sense here.  A map is for associating different keys and values, while you are keeping track of lists of different objects.  I would say that you need to get rid of the counters as they are not needed.   If you need the count for a specific list, you just call `List.size()`.

If you wanted, you could still use a map like so: `Map<String, List<abcIdentifierObject>>`.  The keys would be constants defined like so: "Successful, Failure, ExceptionBoa, SuccessfulBoaSettlement". 
However, it wouldn't make much of a difference since your keys are finite and already defined.  It would be just as verbose, if not more.

Stick with the lists and please follow the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maps and Lists are very different concepts.

Choose a List when you need an ordered collection of (one type of) objects.

Use a Map when you want to store relationships, associating keys (objects of one type) with values (objects of another type).

There is very little overlap between these.  If you want to store relationships, use a Map; otherwise, don't!